# Is there a way to ssh using hostname alias without modifying the etc/hosts file?

Tags: ssh, hostname, route, hosts, hosts-file

I spent hours researching how I can automate 100s of hosts that are all under one local domain. (i'm on a ubuntu linux 17.04 machine)

For example, I have node1.domain.org, node2.domain.org, and the list goes to node100.domain.org

it is practically impossible to edit the /etc/hosts file adding all the alias manually.

For example,

> 127.0.0.1       localhost
>
> 127.0.1.1       harish
>
> ## manually adding hostname aliases
>
> 10.2.1.3        node1.domain.org   node1
>
> ## The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
>
> ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
>
> fe00::0 ip6-localnet
>
> ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
>
> ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
>
> ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

I tried the `ip route | grep default` and found that the gateway to be 10.1.10.1 but not clue if I should be on this gateway or of any further steps from here.

I tried `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and found the DNS Server I'm using

> cat /etc/resolv.conf
>
> ## Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
>
> DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
>   
>   127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
>   
>   run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
>
> nameserver 10.2.254.254 nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 127.0.0.53
>
> search domain.com

I found the DNS that all my nodes are using

> xcat node1 dns
>
> SERVER: 10.2.254.254#53(10.2.254.254)

Both remote node dns and my localmachine dns matched.

However, No clue why it is domain.com in resolve.conf file and not domain.org as all the nodes are under domain.org and not domain.com (but it told it will overwrite when I try to edit it and it did.  I tried to run 'sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart' or 'sudo service network-manager restart' after updating it to domain.org and the file is overwritten). I observed that can SSH using all aliases such as `node1` without using `node1.domain.org` when I did this change but the file is always overwritten on system restart or when i go on to wifi connection instead of Ethernet connection.

I also tried verifying the `route` command and everything looks normal, still no clue

> route
>
> Kernel IP routing table
>
> Destination     Gateway         Genmask Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
>
> default         gateway         0.0.0.0 UG    100    0        0 enp2s0f1
>
> 10.1.10.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0f1
>
> link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000 0        0 enp2s0f1

All I want is to 
ssh node1 instead of ssh node1.domain.org
or
ssh node50 instead of ssh node50.domain.org
or
do ssh into any node using its alias without adding it manually to /etc/hosts. I just want to find out a robust way to do this.

Comment: It's not difficult to do this, and it's not even difficult to add hundreds of hosts to a hostfile. Whatever websites you were using, never use them again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use ~/.ssh/config

```
Host bsd1
        Hostname 10.9.9.2
        User bsduser
        Port 2243
Host web-backup
        Hostname www-backup.example.com
        User dauser
        Port 2229
```

Basically, after each Host statement, you can use pretty much any option that would be valid in the system-level ssh_config

Then simply ssh to whatever tag for the host you have to do is -

```
user@darkstar:~/ $ ssh web-backup
dauser@www-backup.example.com's password:
```

Comment: You forgot to disable password authentication.

Comment: Perhaps. But then look at the IP - I basically copy/pasted something from my config, which I use for experimental vms....

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, it's effortless.

In `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host node* server*
  Hostname %h.domain.org
```

Now every “node” and “server” is mapped to the domain.

`$ ssh node04` --> `$ ssh node04.domain.org`

`$ ssh server12` --> `$ ssh server12.domain.org`

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use your ssh client config (~/.ssh/config):

```
Host node1
    Hostname node1.domain.org
```